# "Error in table(pred = prediction, true = W[, 8]) : all arguments must have the same length"

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm

this is my data:

```
 Anon_Student_Id           Problem_Hierarchy Problem_Name Problem_View Number_Of_Steps Sum_Of_Steps_Duration Sum_Of_Hints result
1      80nlN05JQ6 Unit ES_01, Section ES_01-6         EG21            8               3                    28            0      1
2      80nlN05JQ6 Unit ES_01, Section ES_01-6         EG21            9               3                    37            0      0
3      80nlN05JQ6 Unit ES_01, Section ES_01-6         EG21           10               3                    50            0      0
4      80nlN05JQ6 Unit ES_01, Section ES_01-6         EG22            1               3                    78            0      0
5      80nlN05JQ6 Unit ES_01, Section ES_01-6         EG22            2               3                    41            0      1
6      80nlN05JQ6 Unit ES_01, Section ES_01-6         EG22            3               3                    92            0      0
```

I'm trying to predict the attribute "result" by SVM model :

> model<-svm(result~., scale=FALSE, data=W)
>
> prediction <- predict(model, W[,-8])
>
> table(pred = prediction, true = W[,8])

But I get this error:

```
"Error in table(pred = prediction, true = W[, 8]) : 
  all arguments must have the same length"
```

When I checked it I got: length(pred)=2042 and length(true)=2043

Why I'm getting this error?? (I mean- why i'm getting different lengths? "pred" and "true" are supposed to have the same length)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I miss something but 2042 != 2043, isn't it?

Comment: of course but why i'm getting different lengths?

Comment: @agstudy obviously 2042 == 2043, to within a margin of error. @OP: you might have an NA somewhere in your dataset. The `predict` function should give an NA prediction, but it's possible it's just dropping that case entirely. Post the package you're using to fit the SVM.

Comment: @HongOoi :) good point! I guess it is `e1071` package.

Comment: yes, i'm using e1071 package.

Comment: someone knows about this error?

Comment: maybe the problem is that there is an NA value somewhere. if this is the case, how can i find it, or make svm give an NA prediction for this value? 
thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved:
i got rid of all the na values of my data using na.omit(W) and then it worked. 
thank you!