# how to correct different vector lengths caused by NA's?

Tags: r

I’ve been following [these procedures](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwogTI8d6EEiRTZjaEEzZVNPU0E/edit) for my dataset, but only for a probit model. The problem is that I haven’t been able to get the results for the `table()` function application; the output goes like this:

> Error in table(true = y, pred = round(fitted(probit))) :    all
>   arguments must have the same length

It’s clear that the problem here is the different length of the vectors, but I can’t figure out why do they have different lengths. As `y` is the dependent variable vector used in the probit estimation and `round(fitted(probit))` a transformation for the regression’s result, shouldn’t they have the same length? I’ve also noticed that fitted(probit) “shrinks” my vector to 54% the length of the dataset.
The actual lengths are:

```
length(y)  
#[1] 445815    
length(pred)  
#[1] 243300
```

Why is it happening? What is the procedure behind the `fitted()` function in R that leads to this result? How to solve this problem?
I’ve tried to use na.omit(dataset) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155614/error-in-tablepred-prediction-true-w-8-all-arguments-must-have-the) but it had no effects. Nevertheless, there might be another cleansing problem with the dataset that is driven the results to this.

Comment: This might happen with NA's in your `X`-dataset, but as joran says, we cannot read your computer's "mind", so any comment will be a guess.

Comment: It was really a matter of `NA's` in dataset. The vector decreased in the proportion of the rows that contained 1 or more `NA's`. `na.omit(y)`, or `na.exclude(y)` doesn't work, because the `y` variable, has no `NA's` throughout it's length. My solution was to remove from the dataset all rows that had `NA's`, forcing `y` to the same length as the rest of the data and the same length as the estimation output. I've used `dataset[complete.cases(dataset),]` 
 `table(true = dataset$y, pred = round(fitted(probit)))`  Althought I'm not sure if excluding these lines is metodologicaly the right move.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility (still a guess but a better informed one.) I'm assuming the data argument to `glm` was `X` (as it was named in the linked documnet), but if otherwise, you should adjust the code appropriately. The `complete.cases` function returns a vector of logicals calculated rowwise on a dimensioned object like a matrix or dataframe and is suitable for selection:

```
 table(true = y[complete.cases(X)], 
       pred = round( fitted(probit ))
```

Comment: In fact I had to apply the `complete.cases` function to `y`, for the probit model fit already gets rid of `NA's` observations. It worked. The only problem is that it may not be metodologicaly correct.